# How to count occurences at the end of the list

Tags: python

I would like to count the same occurences at the end of the list in python. It's very trivial to do, but I'm interested in some of your interesting solutions as well. List can contain only '1' or '2' item. Result must be in [3,4,5]. If less than 2 quit, if more than 5 return 5.

**Examples:**

Let's have

```
  L = [1,1,2]
  Result: None (quit)

  L = [1,2,1,1]
  Result: None (quit)

  L = [1,2,1,1,1]
  Result: 3

  L = [1,1,2,2,2,2]
  Result: 4

  L = [1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1]
  Result: 5
```

Comment: Interesting task. I like solving puzzles like this one. :)

Comment: What I like about answers for this kind of questions is that every time comes somebody who is able to do that with one-liner. There I see I should study really more about the language syntax :)

Comment: True, this is really astonishing. But as you can see from the answers, it's not always the recommended way of doing it in one line. Replacing the vertical code length by a horizontal one doesn't necessarily simplify the code. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `itertools.groupby` by taking advantage of the fact that it will group keys separately if they are unsorted (this returns `False` for < 2 just for the sake of showing the output - you can change to whatever you want). With `groupby`, you get an iterable that takes the form `(key, values)`, where `values` is another iterable that contains all values relating to the key. In this case, we don't care about the key (hence the `_`), and we convert the `values` to a list and then take the length of it (this results in a list of lengths that would look like `[1, 1, 2]` in the case of `[1, 2, 1, 1]`). We then take the last item from that list which will represent the number of times the last element is repeated. From there, we apply the logic of which value to return:

```
In [1]: from itertools import groupby

In [2]: def my_func(l):
   ...:     val = [len(list(g)) for _, g in groupby(l)][-1]
   ...:     if val < 3:
   ...:         return False
   ...:     return min(val, 5)
   ...: 

In [3]: 

In [4]: L = [1,1,2]

In [5]: my_func(L)
Out[5]: False

In [6]: L = [1,2,1,1]

In [7]: my_func(L)
Out[7]: False

In [8]: L = [1,2,1,1,1]

In [9]: my_func(L)
Out[9]: 3

In [10]: L = [1,1,2,2,2,2]

In [11]: my_func(L)
Out[11]: 4

In [12]: L = [1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1]

In [13]: my_func(L)
Out[13]: 5
```

Comment: Hm one question came to my mind.. how the groupby statement should look like, if I wanted to use custom iterator - (the list does not contain int, but another objects which hold 1/2 values). What I mean by custom iterator - the iterator not implemented by overloading \_\_iter\_\_ of the list. Thank you.

Comment: @Memo Will expand on this more in a bit, but the short answer is that `groupby` is very flexible in how it groups. You use this functionality by supplying the `key` argument, which determines how the iterable should be grouped. In your case, you would want to supply a function that would return whatever element you are using to differentiate your objects. That probably sounds a bit convoluted so I will update with an example in a little bit :)

Comment: The value 1/2 is hidden under L[i].object1.attr1

Comment: Ok count = [len(list(g)) for _, g in groupby(l, lambda x: x.object1.attr1)][-1] did the thing. Thank you much.

Comment: @Mejmo Ha, well you're a quick study, nicely done :) One thing to note is that usually you need to sort the data in order to get the behavior that you want - this happens to be one of the less common cases where you can take advantage of the non-sorted behavior. Glad you got it sorted out and happy to help if anything else comes up.

Answer (score 2):

I fulfil the boring job of giving a readable answer. ;) It works with all kinds of elements, not just `1`s and `2`s.

```
In [1]: def list_end_counter(lst):
  ....:     counter = 0
  ....:     for elem in reversed(lst):
  ....:         if elem == lst[-1]:
  ....:             counter += 1
  ....:         else:
  ....:             break
  ....:     if counter < 3:
  ....:         return None
  ....:     elif counter > 5:
  ....:         return 5
  ....:     return counter
```

A slight modification to save some lines:

```
In [1]: def list_end_counter(lst):
  ....:     def stop():
  ....:         raise StopIteration()
  ....:     counter = sum(1 if elem == lst[-1] else stop() for elem in reversed(lst))
  ....:     return None if counter < 3 else 5 if counter > 5 else counter
```

Both give the correct results:

```
In [2]: print list_end_counter([1,1,2])
None

In [3]: print list_end_counter([1,2,1,1])
None

In [4]: print list_end_counter([1,2,1,1,1])
3

In [5]: print list_end_counter([1,1,2,2,2,2])
4

In [6]: print list_end_counter([1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1])
5
```

Comment: I believe this is a thematic way to solve these kind of problems.

Comment: @Akavall What exactly do you mean by *thematic*?

Comment: I guess what I meant is that it is pseudo-code like; you could use this idea in any language, +1 for that.

Comment: @Akavall Yeah, I like the pseudo-code like nature of Python very much. That's why I prefer writing readable code over saving code lines. I'm feeling reassured when I see the other answers. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Comedy one line answer:

```
def countOccurencesAtTheEndOfTheList(L):
    return (lambda num: None if num <= 2 else min(5, num))(len(L) if all(map(lambda x: x == L[-1], L)) else len(L) - 1 - [idx for idx, x in enumerate(L) if x != L[-1]][-1])

print countOccurencesAtTheEndOfTheList([1,1,2])
print countOccurencesAtTheEndOfTheList([1,2,1,1])
print countOccurencesAtTheEndOfTheList([1,2,1,1,1])
print countOccurencesAtTheEndOfTheList([1,1,2,2,2,2])
print countOccurencesAtTheEndOfTheList([1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1])
```

output:

```
None
None
3
4
5
```

Explanation:

`[idx for idx, x in enumerate(L) if x != L[-1]]` Gets the indices of each element of L that do not match the last element. 
`[idx for idx, x in enumerate(L) if x != L[-1]][-1]` Gets the index of the rightmost element that does not match the last element. This is only valid if all of the elements in the list are not identical.
`len(L) - 1 - [the above line]` gets the number of elements at the end of the list that match the last element, if all of the elements in the list are not identical. 
`all(map(lambda x: x== L[-1], L)` returns True only if all of the elements in the list are identical.
`len(L) if [the above line] else [the line above the above line]` gets the number of elements at the end of the list that match the last element, regardless of whether all the elements in the list are identical or not.
`lambda num: None if num <= 2 else min(5, num)` returns `None` if the value is too low, and clamps the maximum possible value to 5.

Warning: for entertainment purposes only. Please do not write code like this.

Comment: Haha, +1 for the entertainment

Answer (score 1):

Here's another idea:

```
def count(l):
    n = l[::-1].index([2,1][l[-1] - 1])
    return min(n, 5) if n > 2 else None

print count([1,1,2])
print count([1,2,1,1])
print count([1,2,1,1,1])
print count([1,1,2,2,2,2])
print count([1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1])
```

```
None
None
3
4
5
```

Comment: Ha, I like this more than mine, +1 (always like solutions that use smart logic :) ).

Comment: Interesting, but not very readable. ;) (At least not for me.)

Comment: @PeterStahl Well it relies heavily on the assumption that the list contains only `1`s and `2`s. :P

Answer (score 0):

'index' method of lists can be used to do the search.
I'm assuming that if the list is all 1, you want the same result as when a single 2 is prepended to that list; and if all 2, the same result as if 1 is prepended...

```
def mejmo_count( lst ):

    if len(lst) >= 3:          # otherwise answer is None
       tail = lst[-2:-6:-1]    # extract last part, reversed (omit final)
       x = 3-lst[-1]           # search for this..
       n = (tail + [x]).index(x) # find the first x (sentinel found if not present)
       if n >= 2:             # n can be 0..4 here
           return n+1
    return None
```